# Invalid DateTime with correct format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse this date `22.07.20` into a `DateTime` object, so I did:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
namespace Rextester{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            var c =  DateTime.ParseExact("dd.MM.yy", "22.07.20", null);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

but I get:

> Run-time exception (line -1): String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I know that this question was asked several times already, but I didn't found any solutions for my specific problem, what I did wrong?

Comment: Swap the order of format and date in the method. Replace null by CultureInfo.InvarientCulture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the correct argument order for this function. The function signature looks like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

So your parse function should look like this:

```
var c = DateTime.ParseExact("22.07.20", "dd.MM.yy", null)
```

Comment: Thanks dude, a really stupid error.. have a nice day!

Comment: @sfarzoso - If this answer solved your problem then please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity yep, I'm waiting stackoverflow time limit